# Subgit installer For windows

Tags: subgit

I am trying to migrate from SVN to Git with history data and someone suggests me to use SubGit for this.
I downloaded the zip file and found that there is subgit.bat available in the bin folder after extracting it.

I don't know how to run subgit and ensure subgit installed on my windows system or not because it's throwing me subgit: Command not found

Comment: Ensure whether `$PATH` variable is updated with SubGit extracted path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SubGit doesn't require any special installation, you can just unzip it and start to use, the bin/subgit.bat is actually SubGit start script. For convenience sake, it may worth to add the path to SubGit 'bin' folder to PATH environment variable so that subgit can start without issuing the full path every time.

The 'Command not found' error means that Windows cannot find the 'subgit' command -- it happens when there is no program called 'subgit' neither in PATH, nor in current directory. To resolve it either use full path to the 'subgit.bat' file to start the program (like, c:\subgit\bin\subgit.bat) or add SubGit bin directory path to PATH.